# Expressing $2\cos^2x+\sin^2x$ in terms of $\cos2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

For the expression
$$2\cos^2x+\sin^2x$$
I have to express it in terms of $\cos2x$. I have got to
$$2\cos^2x+(1-\cos^2x)=\cos^2x+1$$
and I am unable to proceed.

Comment: $$\cos 2x=2\cos^2x -1 $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$\cos(2x)=\cos(x+x)=\cos x\cos x-\sin x\sin x=\cos^{2}x-\sin^{2}x=\cos^{2}x-(1-\cos^2{x})=2\cos^2{x}-1$$

So,
$$\cos^2{x}=\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}$$

which can be substituted.

Comment: I know this identity however I do not know how to transform the expression into something similar hence expressing it in terms of cos2X

Comment: @user370016 Is it fine now?

Comment: This was very obvious thanks for pointing it out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

cos(2x) = cos^2(x) - sin^2(x) = 2 cos^2(x) - 1 = 1 - 2 sin^2(x)

it is a general formula.
so you can use it to do similar sums